# How to make Google Chrome tab's "x" button trigger Task Manager => End Process?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Is there a way to change Google Chrome's default tab closing behavior to trigger the equivalent of opening Task Manager and clicking End Process?

**Edit:** I'm on Mac OS

Comment: This closed question on stackoverflow seems to be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799854/keyboard-shortcut-to-end-process-for-chrome-tab

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you would have to rewrite some Chrome code for that, which I don't think is the kind of answer you were looking for.

However, you could easily write a short batch script which would forcefully close Chrome on double click :
Windows : `taskkill -im chrome.exe`
Mac/Linux : `killall 'Google Chrome'`
which does the same as Task Manager > End task.

Or even :
Windows : `taskkill -f -im chrome.exe`
Mac/Linux : `killall -9 'Google Chrome'`
The `-f`/`-9` forcefully terminates the process(es).

Save either line in a `Kill Chrome.bat` / `Kill Chrome.sh`, for example, somewhere accessible like your desktop. Whenever you need to kill Chrome because it does not respond, double click the batch file.

Comment: Very good for a first post +1, keep up the good work, and yes, that also helped me, I always used Task Manager, thanks to your post, I have created a batch file that allows me to click and close a 3rd-party explorer that always hangs on me. (P.S. I knew that program existed but never really __TaskKill /?__ took time to learn it, thank you.)

Comment: Thanks and you're very welcome !

Comment: Unfortunately that kills Chrome as a whole, not just a single tab. Also sorry for not specifying that but I'm using Mac OS.

Comment: Indeed. To kill a single tab you would have to get its pid amongst all the chrome processes. I'm editing the answer for Mac